# Nested tmux: Key combo to "enter" inner tmux, use regular key bindings and combo to exit to outer tmux and use same combos

Tags: shell, tmux

I've been using tmux heavily and I am using it nested all the time. 
At the moment I have to do C-a (I remapped default one) twice and then send tmux commands to inner tmux session.

I was wondering is it possible to have something like: hit C-q (or whatever) which will 'enter' you into inner tmux, and there all default bindings (with C-a, using same tmux.conf) would work until you hit C-q again (or whatever) which would exit you to outer tmux.

Is this possible? Hoping this question makes sense.. Thanks :)

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on  http://superuser.com or another StackExchange site. Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. ***Please*** read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck.